# ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have some problem with my code:

### Models:

```
class UsefulPhrase < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :useful_phrase_contents
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :useful_phrase_contents
   validates_presence_of :key
end
```

---

```
class UsefulPhraseContent < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :useful_phrase
   attr_accessor :useful_phrase_id
   validates_presence_of :language, :content
end
```

---

### Controller:

```
def new
  @useful_phrase = UsefulPhrase.new
  @available_languages = available_languages
  @useful_phrase.useful_phrase_contents.build
end

def create
  @useful_phrase = UsefulPhrase.new(useful_phrase_params)
  @useful_phrase.useful_phrase_contents.build(upc_params)

  respond_to do |format|
   if @useful_phrase.save
     format.html { redirect_to @useful_phrase, notice: 'bla-bla' }
     format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @useful_phrase }
   else
     format.html { render :new }
     format.json { render json: @useful_phrase.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
  end
end

def useful_phrase_params
   params.require(:useful_phrase).permit(:key)    
end


def upc_params
    params.require(:useful_phrase).require(:useful_phrase_content).permit(:language, :content)
end
```

---

When i'm trying save any record I get:

> ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError at /useful_phrases
>       can't write unknown attribute `useful_phrase_id`

I don't know how to repair it.

Comment: I think the issue is coming for the `attr_accessor ` you have in your `UsefulPhraseContent` class. What are you trying to do with that?

Comment: When i removed attr_accesor i got: 'ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError at /useful_phrases/new
unknown attribute "useful_phrase_id" for UsefulPhraseContent.'

Comment: Look at this thread to see if you need to update your rails version https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13432

Comment: In your `upc_params`, try also permitting `:id` or `:useful_phrase_id`

Comment: I added `:id`, `:useful_phrase_id` and still `can't write unknown attribute "useful_phrase_id"`. I edited my create method, and saved only `@useful_phrase.useful_phrase_contents.build(upc_params)` and this is "ok" - i saved only UPC without up_id. Has someone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

try edit your parameter in your upc_params

params.require(:useful_phrase)
      .permit(:language, content, :useful_phrase_content => [puttheattributefor use_ful_phrase_content])